# Why is scalar field self-interaction quartic in the Lagrangian?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, potential-energy, higgs, self-energy

From https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNcTOSx2eMs at 11:34

> the Higgs field is called a free field because it has no sources, no kinds of charges from which it emanates ... the fact that it is self sourcing means that it also interacts with itself ... it turns out that these self interactions will give an extra kind of potential energy to the field  ... the potential energy of a free scalar field doesn't just depend on Phi squared it has to have what we call a quartic as well

$$L=\frac{1}{2}(\delta_\mu\phi)^2 - (\frac{1}{2}\mu^2\phi^2 + \frac{1}{4}\lambda\phi^4)$$

Why are there no sources?

Why does having no sources imply that there is self-interaction? Do fields with sources *not* have self-interaction?

Why is this self-interaction quartic in the Lagrangian?

Comment: I didn't watch the video, but the speaker/writer seems to be confused about the language. The way most physicists use the words, "free field" means no interactions with anything. The Higgs field is *not* a free field. Also, "self-sourcing" is not a term that I've seen other physicists use in this context. The way most physicists use the word "source" in quantum field theory, the existence of a source doesn't say anything (one way or the other) about the existence of self-interactions.

Comment: "Why is this self-interaction quartic in the Lagrangian?"  Because this is the lowest order self interaction that doesn't disturb the symmetry of the ground state.

Comment: @LewisMiller can you please expand on that?

Comment: Prior to adding the self-interaction the effective potential satisfies $V(\phi)=V(-\phi)$.  Adding a quartic self-interaction preserves this symmetry but a cubic self interaction would not.

Comment: Why does $V$ have to be an even function? And why couldn't self-interaction be a quadratic term, or sextic, or a constant?